# How to get more votes on answers to my question?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question regarding best practices in SharePoint 2013.

[Best practice for deploying Site Columns and Content Type](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/65801/15865)

The two answers cover the options that we were considering, but with one vote each, it is hard to decide which should be considered a best practice.

If I wanted more answers, I would start a bounty.  How do I get the community to respond to  the answers to my question?

Side Note:
I kinda feel like this question might be "Not Constructive", as it feels like a polling question, which is why I am trying to ask from the "Best Practice" standpoint, not a "what is the best/your favorite".  If you still think this is "Not Constructive", I won't be upset if the question gets closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the beauty of Stackexchange - you have to chose one, and only one, accepted answer to your question. It means that this is the answer you accepted, not the one the community accepted - you did.

But if there's a big difference in votes between your accepted answer, and the most upvoted answer - there's a consolation prize for the one with the most upvoted answer too (apart from gaining reps). That is the [Populist](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/badges/49/populist) gold badge (not yet awarded here though), but I'm sure it'll come. To earn the badge you need to have the:

> Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

So my advice is - pick the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: Why the downvote, folks?  Why are there so many trolls out there?  I'm an anti-troll.  This is a decent answer, in my opinion: +1.

Comment: @BGM Thanks. It could be a nummer of reasons which I've stop worrying about if down voter doesn't post a comment.

Comment: Maybe there are reasons, but it's rude, and isn't constructive. I wonder if it wouldn't be better if folks HAD to post a comment before they could downvote?  I see some poor folks over on SO who, on their first post get a downvote without any offer to help them understand.  And sometimes it's not even that bad of a question.  Trolls!