# How to Get More Attention

Tags: discussion

Sometimes you might ask a question and time passes...

and passes...

and passes...

Then you get tired of waiting and since nobody answers your question, or comments, or even gives you a vote of support, you forget you asked that question.

Then a year later you go searching for the answer to a particular problem and you google up... voila! - [your very own question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113061/page-viewer-webpart-not-consistent)!  With no answers, no comments and no votes.

When I post a question here it is because I can't solve it myself and need some help.  It is so disappointing to get no attention at all - no answers, no comments, no votes - and even worse if your question ends up with lots of views.  [I expressed my discouragement about this in another post](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/879/hard-time-getting-both-answers-and-votes).

Now, I'm not asking [how to get more votes](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/834/how-to-get-more-votes-on-answers-to-my-question); I'm looking for attention.

So my question here for the meta is, how can you get more attention for your question besides offering a bounty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bounties is of course part of the solution to get more attention (the pricy way).

Two other ways I can think of:

1. Make sure to tag your post with all relevant tags (to make it show up easier in searches etc.)
2. Write your posts so that they are easy to understand, and with as much details as possible. This make questions more attractive to answer for users in a hurry.

Also, try to limit the scope of each question. Sometimes it is better to ask two questions instead of one, to narrow down what needs to be answered in each of them. This way, users not knowing the answer to the broader question can still help you by answer the narrower questions (and thereby give you a part, or the whole, solution)

Note, the word *your* above is not targeted at any one specific individual :)

Comment: So, if "you" have made every attempt to do these things, I guess there isn't much you can do after that, except offer a bounty.

Comment: I think you really should consider offering a bounty, it really gives your question the attention it needs

Answer (score 2):

In my experience sometimes the question is just a really hard one to answer, or takes a bit of thinking to solve the question. There have been questions I've asked that take a very experienced SharePoint expert to answer, a very specific scenario, or a user that has come across the same exact problem, so 95% of users that read through have no idea how to solve the problem at hand.

Like @Robert Lindgren said, sometimes its the way you ask your question. Only provide the details that are absolutely necessary for explaining the problem. History, personal thoughts, related problems, extra verbage, etc. can be omitted. I know for me, if the question has a lot of content to it, it's tiring to filter through everything to get to the problem of the question.